# why ng2-smart-table doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

It doesn't display.

```
"dependencies:
"array.from": "^1.0.3",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
"babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",

devDependencies:
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0","
```

I also added above dependencies.

Comment: Does the rest of your app work in IE11?

Comment: Yes, ng2-smart-table is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uncomment below polyfills for Internet Explorer. It only supports IE-11 and IE10

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
    import 'core-js/es6/object';
    import 'core-js/es6/function';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
    import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
    import 'core-js/es6/number';
    import 'core-js/es6/math';
    import 'core-js/es6/string';
    import 'core-js/es6/date';
    import 'core-js/es6/array';
    import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
    import 'core-js/es6/map';
    import 'core-js/es6/set';


    /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
    import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```